# Go range over uint8 slice?

Tags: go

*EDIT This was due to a stupid error in my part, but the question is worth keeping around in case someone else does this.*

I would hope that this works:

```
var xs []uint8
var x uint8
for x = range xs {

}
```

But I get the error:

```
cannot assign type int to x (type uint8) in range
```

i.e. (as I understand it) the `range`, even though it is operating on a slice of `uint8`, is trying to use `int` as the iterated value.

I have looked through the language spec, the relevant bit:

```
Range expression                          1st value          2nd value (if 2nd variable is present)

array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
```

so I would expect it to be `E` the 'parameterised type'*, in this case `uint8` not `int`.

Have I grasped onto the wrong end of the stick? Is there a bit of documentation that I missed? Or can I really not iterate over a `uint8` slice with a `uint8` variable?

*I know it's not really a generic parameterised type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`range` returns an index into a collection and possibly the value at that position:

> **range keyword** The range keyword allows you to iterate over items of a
>   list like an array or a map. For understanding it, you could translate
>   the range keyword to **for each index of**. When used with arrays and
>   slices, it returns the integer index of the item.
>   ([tutorial](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.de/2011/06/control-structures-go-for-loop-break.html))

sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var xs []uint8 = []uint8{255, 254, 253}
    var idx int
    var ui8 uint8
    for idx, ui8 = range xs {
        fmt.Println(idx, ui8)
    }
}
```

output:

```
0 255
1 254
2 253
```

**P.S.:**

Perhaps a look at Javascript will make Go's approach less strange:

```
% a = [255, 254, 253]
255,254,253
% for (x in a) { print(x, " ", a[x]); }
0 255
1 254
2 253
```

Comment: @Joe - you are welcome; I added the Javascript sample, because I keep forgetting 'it' in than language too often.